# Find lines entering a polygon with QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-plugins, line, crossing

Given a simplified road network
with nodes (= intersections and turning points)
and uni-directional links (= path segments) between them,

I'd like to:

- Know if there is a *plugin* or *processing tool* in QGIS
- Identify / select the links crossing into a (closed) polygon (which outlines an enclosed area of interest)

Something like "terminal point is inside polygon"

*NOTE:*
I do not know the API of QGIS and want to save time, easily edit polygon and check the results or at least learn something, while avoiding to implement a solution using vector algebra.